# Auto Syncing JSON data in Android for a Blog

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-volley, android-syncadapter

i have been working on getting Json data from a blog, parsing it (using the google volley library and Glide for loading the Images) and displaying it in a Linear Recycler View + Card Views, i then stored the post in an SQlite database.

The blog is updated at irregular intervals.
I am confused, as to how to auto sync the json data and show notifications (for new posts) even when the app is not opened. How do i go about this?

I Have heard of Job Scheduler and Sync Adapters.

- is Job Scheduler appropriate? (if yes please point me to a tutorial)
- Sync adapter seem kinda complicated but it appropriate? (if yes please point me to a tutorial).

if neither is appropriate i would appreciate if you can explain how i can successfully achieve my aim.

I am confused, Please Help!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JobScheduler
[Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html)

You can also use AlarmManager [Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) (This also includes starting the service on boot)

I use AlarmManager for syncing my JSON data. When the activity which fetches JSON for the first time runs, I save it in the package data folder and start the alarm. When the Service starts, I download the JSON data and see if it matches with off-line file. If it doesn't, a notification is displayed.

Comment: Thanks i will check it out